# Telerik Reporting Using ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am following this guide -> https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/mvc-report-viewer-extension-embedding

Hi, I created an empty ASP .NET MVC Application and I am trying to output the reportViewer I created. This is what I selected

[image: Add New Item]

I chose the sample report definition.
After that it generated 3 files. A ReportsController, a trdp file and a cshtml file

1. I created a HomeController, and renamed the Action "Index" to "Reports".
2. I Renamed the cshtml file to "Reports.cshtml" and putted it under the Views/Home Folder.
3. Then I created a folder under the Controllers folder called "api" so it now looks like this Controllers/api and moved the ReportsController to that "api" folder.

[image: Solution Explorer]

4. I also changed the default route action from "index" -> "reports"

[image: RouteConfig]

Problem: Whenever I run my program, nothing shows at all. Its just an empty page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Reporting Controller is a Web Api controller, just servers the viewers' HTTP requests. However the razor view page needs a MVC controller to work correctly. For an example of an MVC project see the demos that came with the Telerik Reporting installation.

Another option is to use pure HTML5 page with the Telerik HTML5 Report Viewer Page item template, then the MVC Controller is not needed.